# Angular: abort POST request

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, httpclient, abort

The XMLHttpRequest.abort() aborts the request that was already sent. How could I achieve this in Angular, preferably with HttpClient?

Use case: The application is uploading files. I want the user to be able to cancel the request that is in progress.

Comment: try this - 
this.$http.post('url', function (data) {}, {beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    // use XMLHttpRequest and add xhr.abort callback
}});

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Also I can't see beforeSend property anywhere in the HttpClient definition file. Is this maybe Angular vs AngularJS issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Service:
upload() {
  return this.httpClient.post(); // Some url etc.
}

Component:
  uploadFileSubscription: Subscription;
  uploadFile() {// executed by eg. click
  this.uploadFileSubscription = this.service.upload().subscribe();
}
```

Then whenever you want to cancel that upload request just execute `this.uploadFileSubscription .unsubscribe();`

Comment: I think this just prevents you from seeing the response, it doesn't stop the request that was not already sent and is still in the uploading process (for example if you have a large file). Because it did try that. Or am I making some other mistake?

Comment: I turns out there was another problem :) Thanks for the help @Buczkowski

Comment: what was the problem? my "takeUntil" or unsubscribe, does not help, the file still goes through in full